# Where should a buffer pedal be placed in the signal chain?

Tags: guitar-effects, effects-pedal

I use a buffer pedal for my signal chain. The buffer pedal, when used correctly,  improves the high frequency response of your overall pedal chain. Everyone knows what it does. **Where should it be used ? At the beginning or the end?** I read an article somewhere that said that high end signal chains include buffer at the beginning and at the end too. **Should it be used on both sides then?** Also a guitar buffer is used these days. Is it necessary even after using a buffer pedal?

Comment: There is a similar question at http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27186/whats-a-buffer-pedal-and-how-to-use-it - but the accepted answer is not ideal.

Comment: Google 'why and when to use a guitar buffer pedal' at 'screaminfx.com.  All you need is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The buffer pedal, when used correctly, improves the high frequency response of your overall pedal chain. Everyone knows what it does.

Unfortunately, this is totally not the case – most guitarists don't know what a buffer does, and I'm afraid both you and [Qweevs](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/48889/932) are among them.

A buffer does **not** boost the treble, and it's also not something necessary before any cable longer than 15 ft.

Actually, the only reason a buffer makes sense is because the electric guitars aren't well-designed. Namely, the pickups have a very high [impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance). As a result, the sound is strongly affected if you connect a cable – the longer the cable, the higher its capacitance, and that together with the built-in inductance (a pickup is essentially just an [inductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor)) creates a high-cut effect.

The correct way to tackle this problem is to redesign the guitar to offer low output impedance. This is most sensibly done with active circuitry – essentially a buffer built into the guitar. With a (properly implemented) active guitar, you should *never* need any buffer pedals, unless perhaps you're feeding a kilometre-long cable.

Unfortunately, active guitars have never took hold on the market (rather unlike active *bass* gutars). This is perhaps in some part to blame on the manufacturers not giving the active circuits proper thought. For one thing, if you simply put a buffer right after the pickups, then these will be able to resonate so strongly that the treble range sounds outright annoying – although tastes vary, for example Brian May's guitar sound makes use of this particular effect. But most pickups actually need a few nanofarads of capacitance to sound good in the usual sense.

Just, they can't bear *too much* load. In particular,

- If you use really long cables. It depends on the guitar what is too much; try a couple of cables and choose the one that sounds best for your taste. That cable should always go before the buffer, if any.
- If you drive low-impedance inputs. This includes the microphone/line-level inputs on mixing consoles, but also some guitar effect pedals. Unlike a cable, these impedances are resistive, not capacitive, which also results in treble loss, but in a different way. For some effects this can actually be desirable, for example the Fuzz Face can make sense to be used unbuffered.

Anyway, as topo morto says, after *any* effects pedal (active, which almost all are), the impedance is decoupled, so using another buffer shouldn't make much difference.

Comment: In your 2nd paragraph (after the quote), you say not needed when longer than 15ft. Based on what I think I read later on, you may have meant to say "shorter?"

Comment: @Yorik: no, I meant a buffer is not something that _always_ becomes necessary as soon as the cable length exceeds 15' – it is just necessary when the signal source is very weak (i.e. high-impedance), like a passive electric guitar.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a signal chain that includes other pedals, and your cable from the guitar to those pedals is fairly short, then you probably don't need a dedicated buffer at all, because *any* other effect pedal that is on (or is not true bypass) *also* acts as a buffer.

If you are not using other effects, or you regularly have all your effects off (and they are all true bypass), or if you have a long cable run to your effects, it might make sense to have a buffer as close to your guitar's output jack as possible.

---

**Edit:** The page at http://screaminfx.com/tech/why-and-when-to-use-a-guitar-buffer-pedal.htm is often suggested as a good place to go and learn about this stuff - but I think it could be slightly misleading. Let's have a look at what they suggest as "Main Places to use a Buffer Pedal":

> 1) Before Really long cable: [image: Before Really long cable]

Here, they are basically correct. Having said that, This 'buffer' could actually be something like a (non-true bypass) Boss tuner, or something like that. So you still may not need to buy a dedicated buffer.

> 2) Many Effects in a Row with True Bypass:
>
> [image: Many Effects in a Row with True Bypass]

This *could* be sensible - but only if all the pedals are true bypass, and *only if you frequently have all of them off*.

> 3) A pedal with low input impedance or one which exhibits tone
>   sucking: [image: A pedal with low input impedance or one which exhibits tone sucking]

This is a case where you should really try it and see. Many pedals of the type they are referring to (wahs, and 'old-school' fuzzes) really don't perform as well (subjectively) when they aren't coupled directly to the guitar's pickup. [ScreaminFX's own buffer](http://screaminfx.com/guitar-stompbox-and-boutique-pedals/clarionix-guitar-buffer-pedal-with-fuzz-safe.htm) claims to have a 'fuzz-safe' facility, but a more reliable (and cheaper) solution might be to put the pedal in a true-bypass looper.

To be fair, screaminFX [also say](http://screaminfx.com/guitar-stompbox-and-boutique-pedals/clarionix-guitar-buffer-pedal-with-fuzz-safe.htm) on another page:

> **"If you are not sure about a buffer, please email me. I will try to
>   talk you out of buying one unless I really think it will help you out.
>   I can usually talk half of the people out of buying one. Many pedals
>   already have buffers in them, some are always on"**

This is a commendable statement.

---

One final point - in a lot of these discussions, people suggest "try it and see" (as I have above, in one case) - but remember that expectation bias can be strong. **Don't *expect* a buffer to improve your sound, because in many situations there is no reason to think that it will make much difference**. Even when it does, some people may still prefer the unbuffered scenario!